# Cells in the MicroSoft Excel 2010 are completely transparent. How to make this cell appearance more clear?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-2010

Below is the system configuration i'm using.

Operating system : Windows 10
Microsoft Excel 2010.

Here is the screenshot of the excel appearance.
[sample_excel_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztae5.png)

Can anyone help me to change some settings so that i can see the cells clearly.

Thanks

Comment: Your screenshot looks normal to me.  It isn't clear what aspect is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The default gridlines are quite light.  You can either:

1. darken the gridlines
2. use Borders

To darken the gridlines, use Advanced Options:

[image]

To use Borders, just select the cells and use the Ribbon commands:

[image]